# Logo Issue/Challenge - Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, graphical-logo

I'm stuck on a small part of the logo, trying to make something different using Bootstrap's navigation bar. What I'm trying to achieve is the logo having a border bottom radius of 50px! (almost rounded), and all the other corners square. The issue here is the left and bottom part of logo div is cut because is inside of a container, tried to put the logo outside the container, and playing with the media queries and trying to achieve the effect that I want, but nothing so far.

[image: Example]

Is possible? I tried putting the the logo outside the navigation bar, and gave it a padding-left of 10% to push the logo where the container starts, but I feel is not that good technique. Even tried adding a secondary div, and tried filling

I made a small example on Codepen - [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByqERm)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things actually:

1. If I understand right you need the left bottom corner to be rounded as well. In this case you need to add also `border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;`
2. If so it's a problem with the negative margin that bootstrap adds to its navbar-brand so you want that overwritten.

   ```
   .site-logo .navbar-brand {
       margin-left: 0 !important;  
   }
   ```

[Here's the updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJxQwb) (I made the background red to see it better)

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response, and yes you understood right, but AGAIN, my explaining is not bad, is very BAD. What I really want is the space on the left to be filled with the same background color. Here is an example - http://i.imgur.com/daOxzOY.png . I'm going to update the codepen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eadzyg

Comment: In the updated codepen I added a div, with absolute position, aligned to the left, and a max width, but when I re-size the windows it gets messy, but I think in the end I can work with that, using media queries. The main issue for me here was that I was looking for a better technique, not modifying the div css for every breakpoint. I was looking for something fluid with 100% width or auto. Thank you thought. Multumesc

Comment: @MarianStroiu actually you could use the calc function and media queries. Have a look on the updated codepen, with this you won't need an extra div but the calc function isn't supported by IE8  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJxQwb  

What you basically do is calculate the width of the logo container by the following formula: 100% minus container width, and this is where you need to use media queries, for each width that the container takes